# How to create a direct link to an image for other applications to access in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am customizing the checkout page on PayPal.

To provide a logo and header image they require a URL that links directly to the image of the logo or header image such as https://some.domain.name/logo.png. I have to enter this URL on PayPal's website so that it can grab the image from my website to put on their checkout form.

I've tried placing the logo under the public directory and providing the URL: `https://some.domain.name/logo.png`

But this just gives a no route error.

How can I do this in Rails?

Comment: Put your image into `app/assets/images` folder and try again.

Comment: I tried that and I got a no route error

Comment: are you deployed your app? Try `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url("logo.png")` and see what url it generates.

Comment: I get: /assets/provenword_logo-a279b94dc550805d06933b8cf05383785075f28cb5313c9f5fc6db8d7966e130.png.  So I can get the logo if I use the entire path localhost:3000/+ the url to the image. Thank you. Could you put this in an answer so I can accept it. Others might benefit.

Comment: ok, I created answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your images in your `app/assets/images` folder because Rails uses asset pipeline. Then you can use [image_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_url) helper to get a full url, ex:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url("logo.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by direct link the rails way provided the functionalities for get the image link like

```
 image_tag("rails.png")
 # => <img alt="Rails" src="http://some.example.com/assets/rails.png" />
```

put the image on the `app/assets/`

also, put the direct static way like

```
<img alt="Rails" src="app/assets/rails.png" />
```

Here the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

Hope it helps